# The signature of the quadractic Form Q is$ (+,+,0)$? Which of the following statment is true

Tags: linear-algebra

let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2 &0\\0&0&-2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ and define  for  $x,y, z$ $\in R$

$Q(x,y,z) $= $(x,y,z) A \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$

which of the  following satement  is True ?

a) The matrix  of  second order partial derivatives  of  the  quadratics  form Q is $2A$

b) The  ranks  of the  quadratics  form $Q$  is  $2$

c) The  signature  of the  quadractic Form Q is$ (+,+,0)$

d) The  Quadratics Form $Q$ takes  the Value 0 for some non zero vectors $(x,y,z)$

My attempts  :   Matrix  A  has ranks 2  and  it has  2 postive  sigen, and one is 0,,,,in my  thinking  option  2 and and option 3  is correct...

is my answer is correct..??

Any hints/solution will be  appreciated,,,,

i would  be th thanksfuls..

Comment: Why aren't a) or d) correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $A$ can be divided as the sum of a symmetric and a skew part

$$A=B+C=\begin{pmatrix}1&2 &0\\0&0&-2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1 &0\\1&0&-1\\0&-1&1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&1 &0\\-1&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

with $x^TCx=0$
and for the symmetric part $B$ we have

- $\det(1)=1>0$
- $\det\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1 \\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)=-1<0$
- $\det(B)=-2<0$

therefore the signature for $B$ and thus for $A$ is $(+,+,-)$.

Comment: what about option 4 ?? pliz tell me gimusi

Comment: We can exclude now $b$ and $c$, $a$ also can be excluded because $A$ is not symmetric. Threfore oprion $d$ is the correct one. Can you find a vector $v\neq 0$ such that $Av=0$?

Comment: thanks  a lots @Gimusi

Comment: You are welcome! What about the vector $v$?

Comment: To complete the problem you should find such vector $v$. Let try to find it, it is not a difficult task.

Comment: v= (0,0,1)  is it correct ?

Comment: Let try,$ A(0,0,1)=(0,-2,1)\neq 0$. Recall that it suffices to solve $Av=0$.